# How to find the first occurrence of a specific value and replace all subsequent values with NA

Tags: r, replace, sequence, na

I have the follow df in R with columns of binary values (0, 1):

```
    'data.frame':   10 obs. of 7 variables:
     $ Round.1: int  0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
     $ Round.2: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Round.3: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
     $ Round.4: int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Round.5: int  0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Round.6: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
     $ Round.7: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

I would like to (1) find the first incidence of 1 in each column, and (2) replace all subsequent values in the column with NA.

Yielding:

```
    'data.frame':   10 obs. of 7 variables:
     $ Round.1: int  0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
     $ Round.2: int  0 0 0 NA NA 0 0 0 NA 0
     $ Round.3: int  0 0 0 NA NA 0 0 0 NA 0
     $ Round.4: int  0 0 0 NA NA 0 0 0 NA 0
     $ Round.5: int  0 0 0 NA NA 0 0 0 NA 0
     $ Round.6: int  0 0 0 NA NA 0 1 0 NA 0
     $ Round.7: int  0 0 0 NA NA 0 NA 0 NA 0
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For each binary vector `v`, we can try

```
NA^(seq_along(v) > match(1,v,length(v))) * v
```

Example

```
> set.seed(0)

> (df <- as.data.frame(replicate(3, rbinom(10, 1, 0.5))))
   V1 V2 V3
1   1  0  1
2   0  0  1
3   0  0  0
4   1  1  1
5   1  0  0
6   0  1  0
7   1  0  0
8   1  1  0
9   1  1  0
10  1  0  1

> list2DF(lapply(df, \(v) NA^(seq_along(v) > match(1,v,length(v))) * v))
   V1 V2 V3
1   1  0  1
2  NA  0 NA
3  NA  0 NA
4  NA  1 NA
5  NA NA NA
6  NA NA NA
7  NA NA NA
8  NA NA NA
9  NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Will this work for a columns having only `0`?

Comment: @GKi No. I just assume there must be at least one `1`.

Comment: When I look at the data in the question I see 6 columns out of 10 holding only `0`.

Comment: When you change `which.max(v)` to `match(1,v,length(v))` it should work also for those cases.

Comment: @GKi Aha, yes, you are right. I just saw that there is a column of all `0`s. Thanks for the reminder and advice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

1. With `match(1, .)` we get index of the first `1` else `NA` in each column.
2. With `row_number()` we get a vector of the same length as the column, containing the row numbers.
3. With `if_else(row_number() > match(1, .), NA_integer_, .)` we replace all values after the first `1` with a `NA`:

```
df <- structure(list(Round.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Round.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Round.3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Round.4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Round.5 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Round.6 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA), Round.7 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~if_else(row_number() > match(1, .), NA_integer_, .)))
```

```
   Round.1 Round.2 Round.3 Round.4 Round.5 Round.6 Round.7
1        0       0       0       0       0       0       0
2        0       0       0       0       0       0       0
3        0       0       0       0       0       0       0
4        1       0       0       1       1       0       0
5       NA       1       1      NA      NA       0       1
6       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       0      NA
7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1      NA
8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: match() is definitely the way to go here! +1

Comment: As of very recently, dplyr::if_else accepts regular `NA`s, no need for `NA_integer_` anymore

Comment: Oh. that is new for me. thanks for sharing this wisdom @GuedesBF.

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution:

```
test <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
  b = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
)

apply(X = test, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
  idx <- match(1, x)
  
  if (!is.na(idx) & idx < length(x)) {
    x[(idx+1):length(x)] <- NA
  }
  
  x
})

# output
      a  b
[1,]  0  0
[2,]  0  0
[3,]  0  1
[4,]  1 NA
[5,] NA NA
[6,] NA NA
[7,] NA NA
[8,] NA NA
```

Comment: Instead of `apply(X = test, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {` you could try `lapply(DF, \(x) {` or `sapply(DF, \(x) {`.

Answer (score 2):

We can `replace` all values of the columns for which the cummulative max and the lagged cummulative max is 1 with NAs, as the `list` argument in `replace` automatically coerces 1s and 0 into logical for indexing.

```
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame(
  a = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
  b = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
)

test |>
    mutate(across(everything(),
                  \(x) replace(x,
                               cummax(x) & cummax(lag(x, default = 0)),
                               NA)
                  )
           )

   a  b
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  0  1
4  1 NA
5 NA NA
6 NA NA
7 NA NA
8 NA NA
```

Comment: Your code @GuedesBF worked for column-wise replacement, but I'm wondering how the same replacement procedure could be done row-wise. 
Example data:
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1
 [3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
becomes
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [3,]    0    1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, @RCamp, glad to know I helped. This is an entirely new question. You may amend your current question with this new request or create a new one, it is usually better than asking new follow-up questions in the comments section. For rowwise operations, with `dplyr`, we may be looking into `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(...` and use `c_across`

Answer (score 0):

Using `rollapplyr` with a window equal to all elements up to the current element, check if there are any 1's prior to it and output NA if so and otherwise keep the current value.  Note that `any` applied to an empty vector gives FALSE and `head(x, -1)` means all elements of `x` except the last.  See the note at the end for the test input used.

```
library(zoo)

fillna <- function(x) if (any(head(x, -1) == 1)) NA else tail(x, 1)
rollapplyr(df, 1:nrow(df), fillna) |> as.data.frame()
```

giving

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
2 NA NA  0  0  1 NA  0
3 NA NA  0  0 NA NA  0
4 NA NA  0  0 NA NA  0
5 NA NA  0  0 NA NA  0
6 NA NA  0  1 NA NA  0
7 NA NA  0 NA NA NA  0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
1  1  0  0  0  1  0
0  1  0  0  1  0  0
0  1  0  0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  1  0  1  0
0  1  0  1  0  0  0"
df <- read.table(text = Lines)
```